URL Rewrite on IIS
I am referring to the document here
My understanding of url rewrite is, when a request (/folderA/folderB) comes to IIS, URL rewrite is happening at begin-request stage. IIS will rewrite the url to /folderA/folderC, and then IIS will try to fetch document from folderC. However in my case, the URL is not being re-written and then fetching documents from folderA. Below is my directory structure
Root-Folder\
    folderA\
        folderC

From IIS logs, I can confirm that the url is /folderA/folderB. I enabled Failed Request Tracing, however I do not see any xml files that related to rewrite of /folderA/folderB to /folderA/folderC. From Chrome Dev Tools, I can confirm that the request url is /folderA/folderB
The rule defined is for regex pattern of folderA/folderB and action is to rewrite to folderA/folderC.
IIS version is 10, and I am trying to host Angular 16 application.

If you choose the action to be "rewrite" instead of "redirect", then the URL should remain unchanged (so /folderA/folderB is expected). About why your rewrite rule didn't fully work as expected, people need to see the actual rule, not your paragraph of "The rule defined is...". Please locate and open applicationHost.config and see what's the XML representation of your rewrite rule. Then you can edit this question and include that.

As Lex Li said, rewriting the url will not change. If you want to rewrite requests from /folderA/folderB to /folderA/folderC, the content of the request changes, but the URL does not change, you can refer to this rule:
<rule name="Rewrite for folderB">
    <match url="^folderA/(.*)" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="folderA/folderC" />
</rule>

If you also want to change the url, you can refer to this rule:
<rule name="Redirect for folderB">
    <match url="^folderA/(.*)" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="folderA/folderC" />
</rule>

